# Applying Styles in nested listview in WPF

Tags: wpf-controls

I have a listivew inside a listview and I am displaying master detail kind of relationship.

Can i apply the row color of the parent listviewitem to the child listviewitem?

Please reply..

Thanks

Sharath

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
        AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"

Thanks

Sharath